# Difference between unwrapObservable and ()

Tags: knockout.js

Is there an actual difference between:

```
y = ko.observable("value");
x = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(y);
```

and:

```
y = ko.observable("value");
x = y();
```

Should I prefer one of the above and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use ko.utils.unwrapObservable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624401/when-to-use-ko-utils-unwrapobservable)

Comment: @RichardSzalay: You're right, missed that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The difference is that `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` is safe. You should use it when don't know if parameter is observable or not.
For example:

```
function GetValue(x){
   return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(x);
}

function GetValueEx(x){
   return x();
}

var test = 5;
var y = GetValue(test) // Work fine, y = 5;
y = GetValueEx(test) // Error!
```

So if you exactly know that your parameter is observable you can use `()` otherwise use `unwrapObservable`.

EDIT:
A shorter version of `unwrapObservable` has been added in knockout 2.3 - `ko.unwrap`