# Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: TypeError: number is not a function

Tags: knockout.js

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ccOpenInvoiceListObservable">
  <div data-bind="foreach:Invoices">
        <span data-bind="text:$root.formatCurrency(AmountOutstanding)"></span>
  </div>
</div>

 <div data-bind="foreach: overDueBalancesObservable">
        <span data-bind="text: $parent.formatCurrency(OverDueAmount)"></span>  
 </div>

vm.formatCurrency = function (value) {
        return "$" + value().toFixed(2);
};
```

I am getting the error mentioned in the subject line when trying to call $parent.formatCurrency(OverDueAmount). For AmountOutstanding, the values are getting formatted.

Comment: What does the formatCurrency() function look like?  You need to post some more code, what you are showing doesn't appear to be the problem

Comment: I have added the formatCurrency method.

Comment: Is OverDueAmount an observable or a number? If the latter it would error when calling `value()` in the formatCurrency function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because your `OverDueAmount` is not an observable property.

Use the `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` function in your `formatCurrency` to access the `value` (this handles both case when `value` is observable and when it is not see also [When to use ko.utils.unwrapObservable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624401/when-to-use-ko-utils-unwrapobservable)):

```
vm.formatCurrency = function (value) {
        return "$" + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value).toFixed(2);
};
```

Or change your `OverDueAmount` to a `ko.observable`.

Comment: Thanks nemesv, that worked. But both AmountOutstanding & OverDueAmount are properties of ko.observable. Then why value() works for first & not for latter ?

Comment: According to the error `OverDueAmount` is a number and not a ko.observable... are you sure that OverDueAmount is a ko.observable?